# Intuitive Form Design for Assigning Devices to Users

Tags: website-design, interface

Hello. I created a webpage where users can assign unassigned devices to their accounts.

**First there is search view to find the device they want:**

[image: Search View]

As you can see, it's quite simple. Pagination, fields for search rules, table with data and actions.

**After finding a device, the user selects "Claim" and is redirected to a confirmation page:**

[image: Device Claim Confirmation View]

The user only needs to Select "Claim." That's all. Testers have told me that in their opinion this mechanism is unintuitive. So what is good way to design this kind of mechanism?

Can you suggest anything? What is most important in such solutions? What should be redesigned?

Answer (score 2):

On the first screenshot, the claim word is a link, at the same level, position and visual weight than the information one, so both seem to be a side step on a process from the visibility point of view.

If you stop, read the words and think about it, then you realize that both words have completely different kinds of actions and follow ups related, so can start to think that claim is going to be an end of the line/process. But it requires that the user stops and guesses.

Make the claim option a button, separate it from the details action/link with space and/or a vertical line. Space is a must here. Details can be moved beside the product's name, either as a whole word or as an icon.

On the second screenshot, you could change the text from "claim" to "claim the device" to make the action more related to what they are doing and to the process as a concept.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the content of the second window is redundant and maybe should be replaced with a confirmation message; additionally you could add some explanation on what happens when the user confirms the claim.

I think it would make more sense to have the second page as a modal window; something like

```
are you sure you want to claim this device?
when you claim a device this and that happens.
claim | cancel
```

the claim link should be a button; usually, when I'm not sure what to use: link or button, I ask myself if the action changes some info on the item or it just displays some information; button for changing stuff, link for viewing.

Also, is the claim reversible? maybe you could have something like a toggle button

```
item 1     details             claim
```

and after the user claims the device, it becomes

```
item 1     details             release
```